# How to avoid timeout when debugging protractor test?

Tags: debugging, protractor, mocha.js

I'm writing protractor e2e tests and use `browser.pause()` to enter debugger. I appreciate the interactive mode which seems helpful when developing a new test.
However, when I spend too much time in the debuger, the test gets interrupted as timeout is exceeded:

```
     Error: timeout of 240000ms exceeded
```

I can easily fix that by increasing `mochaOpts.timeout` in my protractor configuration, but I don't like changing it back and forth depending if I'm debugging or not.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23492442/4358405

Adding `this.timeout(10000000);` in the test makes the trick

Answer (score 2):

if anyone who reads this and was hoping it was for timing out using Jasmine.

you can put this within your individual spec files

`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 120000; // whatever time you need`

Comment: I apologize I didn't realize you were using mocha