# Mocha Tests runs localy but not on Jenkins

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, mocha.js

I've got strange error with Jenkins. 
When I run localy tests everything is ok. But If I run tests on Jenkins I always get error: 
`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

My before step:

```
before(function () {
return chakram.get(`{baseUrl}/api/cats`)
    .then(apiResp => {
        return getCats= apiResp;
        })
})
```

Comment: Maybe your request needs more time to be processed on jenkins than on your own machine. You can increase mochas timeout with the timout functionality. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492043/change-default-timeout-for-mocha/23492442#23492442)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In mocha testing while calling asynchronous function how to avoid the timeout Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er)

Comment: The error message describes the problem with your code. You never call `done()`

Comment: @codtex calling `done()` is not necessary when returning a promise