# Is there a way to get current Mocha instance and edit options at runtime?

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js

Let's say you have a simple mocha test:

```
describe("Suite", function(){
    it("test",function(doneCallback){
        // here be tests
    });
});
```

In this test I can change the timeout by adding `this.timeout(VALUE);` anywhere within the `describe` function.

However, besides the `timeout` value, there are plenty of other [Mocha options](https://mochajs.org/#mochaopts) that can be exclusively declared either from the command line or from a `mocha.opts` file that lives in the test folder (`./test/mocha.opts`).

What I want is to change some of these options at run-time (for example, the `reporter`) and not in command line / `mocha.opts` file.

From my research of what's possible, I found that there is [an article explaining how you can use mocha programmatically](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically), which would allow changing these options at run-time, but you need to create the `Mocha` instance yourself, whereas in an ordinary test one doesn't have direct access to the `Mocha` instance.

So, is there a way to get the `Mocha` instance from an existent test and change some of these options like `reporter` at run-time during a test?

I would like to have an option that doesn't require to modify the source code of `Mocha` in any way (I suppose I could tamper with the `Mocha` instance to implement a way to get an instance directly in the `Mocha` constructor).

Comment: Looks like you want to follow that article in which you create a mocha instance yourself.

Comment: @kevzettler What article? The one I linked towards? That one requires you to create the `Mocha` instance and `Mocha` runner yourself (add test files etc), whereas I want to use from command line `mocha myTest.js` and have `myTest.js` hook to the `Mocha` instance and be able to modify options at runtime

Comment: yes, the https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically article.

Comment: @kevzettler Can you elaborate how to do it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***No, you cannot.*** without changing the code.

In short, mocha is created in a scope you cannot access from tests. Without going in details, the objects provided  in your scope cannot change the options you want. (You cannot do this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript))

***But*** there is a way to define your own **reporter** and customize the output for each test:

Create a file called **MyCustomReporter.js**:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = MyCustomReporter;

function MyCustomReporter (runner) {

    runner.on('start', function () {
        var reporter = this.suite.suites["0"].reporter;
        process.stdout.write('\n');

    });

    runner.on('pending', function () {
            process.stdout.write('\n  ');
    });

    runner.on('pass', function (test) {
        var reporter = this.suite.useReporter;
        if(reporter == 'do this') {
        }
        else if(reporter == 'do that'){
        }
        process.stdout.write('\n  ');
        process.stdout.write('passed');
    });

    runner.on('fail', function () {
        var reporter = this.suite.useReporter;
        process.stdout.write('\n  ');
        process.stdout.write('failed ');
    });

    runner.on('end', function () {
        console.log();
    });
}
```

When you run mocha, pass the path of MyCustomReporter.js as reporter parameter(without .js), eg:

```
mocha --reporter "/home/user/path/to/MyCustomReporter"
```

The default **mocha script** actually tries to require a reporter file if it is not found in the default ones(under lib/reporters), [github link](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/78b686f3663fbe52ecd54827e5c00af0378292ba/bin/_mocha#L314)

Finally, in your tests, you can pass some parameters to customize the output of your reporter:

```
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
      this.parent.reporter = 'do this';
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
        this.runnable().parent.useReporter = 'do this';
        assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I accepted the answer for the fact that indeed, you can't get the instance from another context and for the fact that [the link you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789892/access-parent-object-in-javascript) was a good resource for me to better understand that. However, the part where you explain how to create a custom reporter, to me, was rambling. I already have one and I wanted to switch from a default reporter (`list`) to a custom reporter, at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

The best way that you can achieve that is by using Mocha as per the wiki link that you have already referenced, which is using Mocha programmatically.

So to your inquiry on changing the `reporter` parameter here is a brief example that would do what you want, in order to run the tests against a theoretically already existing file named `test-file-a.js` that contains your tests:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    mocha = new Mocha(),
    path = require('path');

mocha.addFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test-file-a.js'));

mocha
    .reporter('list')
    .run();
```

Besides that there are plenty other options that you can use and also there are some listeners for events, like `test` that you may want to do something during a test, for example:

```
mocha
    .reporter('list')
    .ui('tdd')
    .bail()
    .timeout(10000) 
    .run()      
    .on('test', function(test) {
        if (test.title === 'some title that you want here') {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Please note that you can define the options per each Mocha instance that will run again a test suite, but **not during the runtime** of a test suite, so for example if you start your tests for `test-file-a.js` with the option `reporter('list')` as above you cannot change it while the tests are running to something else, like you may do for example with the `timeout` option where you can do `this.timeout()`.

So you would have to instantiate a new `Mocha` instance as the examples above with different options each time.