# mocha async/await test failed with timeout

Tags: async-await, mocha.js

I would like to test async codes with `Mocha`.

I followed this tutorial [testing-promises-with-mocha](https://wietse.loves.engineering/testing-promises-with-mocha-90df8b7d2e35). In the end, it says the best way is async/await.

Following is my code, I intended to set setTimeout longer than Mocha default.

```
describe('features', () => {
  it('assertion success', async() => {
    const resolvingPromise = new Promise( resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('promise resolved')
      }, 3000)
    })

    const result = await resolvingPromise
    expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved')
  })
})
```

Mocha give me error as following:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, 
ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves...
```

How to resolve the error? Simple set `mocha --timeout 10000` longer?

Thanks for your time!

```
Mocha: 5.2.0
Chai: 4.2.0
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Mocha has timeout controls. [Mocha docs](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts)

Syntax is:

```
it('should take less than 500ms', function(done) {
  this.timeout(5000); // 5 seconds
  setTimeout(done, 3000);
});
```

Your example:

```
describe('features', () => {
  it('assertion success', async (done) => {
    this.timeout(5000);
    const resolvingPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('promise resolved'), 3000)
    });

    const result = await resolvingPromise();
    expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved');
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: but some steps really take long time to finish. It's not very good to give them a very large timeout right ?

Comment: This will only change the test timeout.  `done()` is added to the end of your test.  Do you mean some steps are just computationally complex and long, or are you testing code that is making API/network requests?  If you're testing code that contains steps that take a long time, increasing the timeout is the best option.  If testing code making external requests, then those API/network requests should be stubbed.  If you're testing code that itself has long timers, then use a library like sinon or similar that mocks and controls the system timer so you manually control ticks.

Comment: Thanks Drew Reese for the information! I'm doing backend testing. Our dev server is in google cloud. So Basically I need to send requests to remote server. I don't want to mock in the test. Some requests are really long to response. I want to avoid this error by adding `done()` to somewhere as it suggested. Because I think adjust timeout is not the best way? Or in this case, I just have to increase timeout?

Comment: You'll need to extend the default timer as well as adding done to your asynchronous tests, that is if the default 2000ms timer prematurely fails your tests.

Answer (score 2):

as you mentioned, --timeout flag does the job.

`node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout <milliseconds>`

you can also check: [Change default timeout for mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492043/change-default-timeout-for-mocha) if you want to set default timeout in whole project.

Answer (score -2):

For async tests you should invoke the `done()` callback.

```
describe('features', () => {
  it('assertion success', async(done) => { // pass done here
    const resolvingPromise = new Promise( resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('promise resolved')
      }, 3000)
    })

    const result = await resolvingPromise
    expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved')
    done() // invoke at end
  })
})
```

Comment: not according to this: https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await