# does mocha intelligently execute async code?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have this code:

```
const mocha = require("mocha");
const assert = require("assert");


describe("saving records", function (done) {
 
  it("Saves a record to the database", function (done) {
    
    let mx = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
      mx = false; //#### note this line
    }, 6000);
    done();

    assert(mx === true);
  });
});
```

I am not sure why, but mocha gives a test pass in the terminal that says:

> saving records
> ✓ Saves a record to the database
> 1 passing (30ms)

**Question no.1 : Why is the test passing at this point**

*The next weird thing is:* It doesn't even wait for 6 seconds seconds before the test passes. Since, I've used `done` parameter, **Question no. 2:** shouldn't it wait until the execution is done?

Have I misinterpreted [some information?](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/08/17/asynchronous-unit-tests-with-mocha-promises-and-winjs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mocha = require("mocha");
const assert = require("assert");

describe("saving records", function (done) {
  it("Saves a record to the database", function (done) {
    let mx = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
      mx = false; //#### note this line
      assert(mx === true);
      done();
    }, 6000);
  });
});
```

In your variant test passes because `assert` is after `done()`;
Working with async tests described [here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)

Comment: it seems there's a default for 2 seconds for waiting for the done() to be reached, can we increase this? So, the test won't stand for 6sec in above case, after 2 seconds it's gonna timeout, how do we increase that?

Comment: Timeout can be any, but you chould set maximum value for test. See docs here https://mochajs.org/#timeouts . Use `this.timeout(ms);` in code or `mocha --timeout 5000` in command. Also good answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492043/change-default-timeout-for-mocha