# getting error when running test for create user

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, chai

Im trying to run a chai test on my website, it should create user when run, but it gives me this error when i run it:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/mikkelwager/Documents/GitHub/Exercise/tests/test.js)
```

- here is my code, can anyone help

  var User = require("../api/models/User");
  const db = require("../api/db/db.js");

  ```
    const chai = require("chai");
    const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
    const router = require("../server");

    chai.use(chaiHttp);
    should = chai.should();

    //test af /opretBruger (krav 1)
    describe("POST /createUser", () => {
      it("It should POST a new user", (done) => {
        const user = {};
        chai
          .request(router)
          .post("/createUser")
          .set('content-type', 'application/json')
          .send({
            first_name: 'test',
            last_name: 'test',
            email: 'test@test',
            phone: '2233223',
            street: 'test',
            zip_code: '1332',
            city: 'test',
            password: 'test',
            member: '1',
          })
          .end(function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
              done(error);
            } else {
              done();
            }
          });
      });
    });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

can you please make it an anonymous function and give it a try or if you have used the faketimers() then remove it.

Comment: How do i make it anonymous? thanks for answer

Comment: please go through this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492043/change-default-timeout-for-mocha . It will fix your issue.